# Loadbalance duplicating the events using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have configuration as filebeat with loadbalance true & two logstash hosts i.e. logstash1 & logstash2 which are input to elasticsearch.
The filebeat configurtion for logstash is as below

```
prospectors:
 -
  paths:
  - /home/testLogs/temp.log
  spool_size: 1
  publish_async: true
### Logstash as output
logstash:
  hosts: ["10.186.187.44:5044", "10.186.187.6:5044"]
  worker: 1
  loadbalance: true
```

The logstash input on both logstash I set as below

```
input {
   beats {
   port => 5044
   congestion_threshold => 100000
   }
}

output {
   stdout {codec => rubydebug}
   elasticsearch {
   hosts => "ipaddress:9200"
   index => "testidx"
   }
}
```

However when I echo some lines into file temp.log, I see that in the elasticsearch processed lines are duplicated docs, it looks to me that both logstash are processing all the lines. and on stdout of both logstash sometime I see forex line1 & line2 processed by both logstash, or sometimes line1 processed by logstash1 & line1, line2, line2 processed by logstash2
However even making loadbalance=flase I still see the duplicated docs. & in stdout I sed line1 & line2 processed twice either by logstash1 or logstash2.

So just wanted to know is my configuration wrong that the lines are not distributed on logstashes or is it like its behavior or bug.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/1.3/logstash-output.html#loadbalance):

> If [loadbalance option] set to true and multiple Logstash hosts are configured, the output plugin load balances published events onto all Logstash hosts.

So it's expected behavior from filebeat to have the events duplicated to the two Logstash.

---

If you want to use two Logstash, you can sent the events to a queue (like redis) and have the Logstash consume from the queue.

Comment: Thanks baudsp for quick reply. 
But I didn't got the point of loadbalance=true here, is it not like it should balance events for the provided hosts i.e. logstashes? 
Secondly when loadbalance is false it is still duplicating when two hosts are provided

Comment: Also when i try to add one more host like below, I am still getting duplicate docs instead of triplicating considering that the each one process the all lines



  hosts: ["localhost:5044", "localhost:5045", "localhost:5046"]

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I have never used filebeat, so I can't tell. But I don't see why you are getting duplicates with loadbalance: false, since it's not the behavior from the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your post, I tested this use-case (because we need it too) with a minimal configuration, and it works. No duplicated documents in elasticsearch.
I tested both, loadbalance true&false.

Filebeat:

```
logstash:
hosts: ["IP-LS1:8098","IP-LS2:8098"]
loadbalance: true
```

Logstash

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 8098
    }
}
filter {...}
output {

    if [type] == "filebeat-test" {
        stdout {codec => rubydebug}
        elasticsearch {
          hosts => ['IP-LS1|IP-LS2:9200']
          index => "filebeat-test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```